# why struct cdev has kobject member?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver

It's strange that `struct cdev` has `struct kobject` member, do any body knows the reason?

Answer (score 2):

When kobjects are embedded inside other structures, the structures receive the standardized functions that a kobject provides. Most importantly, the structure's embedded kobject now enables the structure to become part of an object hierarchy. For example the `cdev` structure is presentable in an object hierarchy via the parent pointer `cdev->kobj.parent` and the list `cdev->kobj.entry`

Source: [Linux Kernel Development by Robert Love](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0672329468)

Answer (score 2):

`Sysfs` is a Virtual filesystem that describes the devices available to the system in hierarchical pattern. This is done by using `struct kobj`.

```
struct kobject {
        char                    *k_name;
        char                    name[KOBJ_NAME_LEN];
        struct kref             kref;
        struct list_head        entry;
        struct kobject          *parent;
        struct kset             *kset;
        struct kobj_type        *ktype;
        struct dentry           *dentry;
};
```

**For any driver kobj is required to export the device attributes to `sysfs`**
 if we consider like `i2c_client` `spi_device`(spi client). we have kobj inside member `struct dev` to export the driver attributes to the user space virtual filesystem(`Sysfs`). The `Kobj` structure members handles all the operations including referring to the device numbers(major/minor) and file operations involved for open, read/write,close etc... of device.

In your case `cdev_init` & `cdev_add` will internally uses kobj to do the above operation.

Answer (score 0):

There are two reasons:

1. [for reference counting](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.15-rc3/source/fs/char_dev.c#L348), which is offered by `kref` internally.

```c
static struct kobject *cdev_get(struct cdev *p)
{
    struct module *owner = p->owner;
    struct kobject *kobj;

    if (owner && !try_module_get(owner))
        return NULL;
    kobj = kobject_get_unless_zero(&p->kobj);
    if (!kobj)
        module_put(owner);
    return kobj;
}

void cdev_put(struct cdev *p)
{
    if (p) {
        struct module *owner = p->owner;
        kobject_put(&p->kobj);
        module_put(owner);
    }
}
```

2. [for release](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.15-rc3/source/fs/char_dev.c#L583), that's also why `kref` is not enough(`kref` doesn't have a release hook).

```c
static void cdev_default_release(struct kobject *kobj)
{
    struct cdev *p = container_of(kobj, struct cdev, kobj);
    struct kobject *parent = kobj->parent;

    cdev_purge(p);
    kobject_put(parent);
}

static void cdev_dynamic_release(struct kobject *kobj)
{
    struct cdev *p = container_of(kobj, struct cdev, kobj);
    struct kobject *parent = kobj->parent;

    cdev_purge(p);
    kfree(p);
    kobject_put(parent);
}

static struct kobj_type ktype_cdev_default = {
    .release    = cdev_default_release,
};

static struct kobj_type ktype_cdev_dynamic = {
    .release    = cdev_dynamic_release,
};
```